# How to send data to a Wordpress post or page from r

Tags: r, wordpress, httr

So I'm in a bit over my head here.  I can GET information from my Wordpress site using httr:

For instance, to get the details of post ID 141, I use this:

```
ws = GET("https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/141")
```

Works fine because the authentication is through cookies I think, and I'm logged into my Wordpress site.

But I can't POST to my wordpress site because (I think) the cookie-type authorization is not allowed.

So this returns a 401 error:

```
POST ('example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/141',
                  body = list(title = "My New Title"))
```

I think I need to send an authorization header, but I'm not sure how to set that up.

Comment: My guess is that you need a basic authorization header containing username and password,

Comment: The OP was provided a link to a resource yesterday that showed how to authorize and use to the modern wordpress API and didn't use the resource. This q is super-similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572579/how-can-i-login-to-my-wordpress-site-using-rwordpress-in-r which was closed.

Comment: Not the same question.. that one was about RWordpress this one is about httr.

Comment: OK, I think I got the answer to this one.